# How to add menu button in Android bottom bar?

Tags: android

In some apps like Skype, FireFox and Angry Birds there is a fourth menu button (which I have tried to draw) on the right which supplies app specific buttons. I want to know how can I add this button and then show some menu when this button is clicked.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to know how can I add this button and then show some menu when this button is clicked.

That is the legacy MENU button. It will be supplied by the OS for older applications (i.e., not set up for Honeycomb, Ice Cream Sandwich, etc.) that have activities with options menus.

New applications being written should either:

-- Use the action bar (`android:targetSdkVersion="11"` or higher), in which case the options menu will appear in the upper-right corner, or

-- Integrate some other menu mechanism directly into the app UI (e.g., for games)

Answer (score 0):

remove target sdk line from manifest
example:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
```